# Creating a df from a filter

Tags: r, filter

I am looking into creating a new data frame from a subset of an existing data frame, applying a filter - in the original data frame the variable is filtered on var1 = 1. When I run this code, it says the var1 object is not found, however, it appears in the data frame when I run summary statistics of the variable in the original data frame. What is happening with the filter?

```
df_filtered <-filter(dataset, var1 >= 1)
 Error in filter(dataset, var1 >= 1): object 'var1' not found

summary(df_filtered$var1)
 Error in df_filtered$var1 : 
 $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

Comment: You may not have loaded `dplyr`.  try `dply::filter(dataset, var1 >= 1)`.

Answer (score 0):

`df_filtered` is not a data frame, it's an atomic vector. What you're attempting to do is use the `$` operator to subset a vector with a length of one. For example, you can get the same error by running:

```r
1$var1
# Error in 1$var1 : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors.
```

Your `filter()` command is not running, because you're attempting to filter a column of `dataset` that doesn't exist - `dataset` does not have a column named `var1`. Because this line fails to execute, you therefore fail to assign anything to `df_filtered`. Presumably that variable name is assigned to an atomic vector in your working environment, for reasons we can only guess at in the absence of a reproducible example. You fail to replace it with a filtered data frame and so it remains an atomic vector.

It's hard to say more than that without a reproducible example.